Time query mysql
I want a query that dynamically fetches data greater than the current time today and less than 24 hours today. If necessary, it should also include data for the next day based on the specified hours value. For example, if I provide hours = 2, the query should fetch data for the next 2 hours from the current time today. However, if I provide hours = 19, the query should return "no rows" if the data does not exist.
Currently, my query retrieves data for today within the next 24 hours, which works fine. However, if I provide a value like hours = 17 or dynamically between 24 hours, it does not include data for the next day if the time exceeds midnight. I need help resolving this issue.
now this query get today data less than or greater than current time..
SELECT *
FROM jobDetails jd
WHERE TIME(time) > TIME(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), '+00:00', '+05:00'))
AND TIME(time) <= TIME(DATE_ADD(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), '+00:00', '+05:00'), INTERVAL ? HOUR));

time store in db like this way
**time**
19:43
02:50
16:48
18:15
16:37
17:00
16:40
16:42
19:13
21:44
03:25
03:25
03:25
03:25
03:25



Provide sample data and desired output. Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question. #5 and #3.

time
19:43
02:50
16:48
18:15
16:37
17:00
16:40
16:42
19:13
21:44
03:25
03:25
03:25
03:25
03:25
this is time column in jobDetails table.
sample data is here and i already define.

Please follow the link. Sample data must be provided as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Add this sample into your question text.

Can you try this:
SELECT *
FROM jobDetails jd
WHERE (
    TIME(time) > TIME(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), '+00:00', '+05:00'))
    AND TIME(time) <= TIME(DATE_ADD(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), '+00:00', '+05:00'), 
INTERVAL ? HOUR))
) OR (
    TIME(time) <= TIME(DATE_ADD(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), '+00:00', '+05:00'), 
INTERVAL ? HOUR))
    AND TIME(time) < TIME(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), '+00:00', '+05:00'))
);


you query give data after the current time and before current time but i don't want before data current time i want data if i give hours = 2 then give me 2 hours data greater than current time & if i give 24 hours then give me data greater then current time how?
